# geolocation works on laptop, but not on smartphone

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet

I created a shiny app for users to choose from a list of addresses (first tab) that they want to have displayed on a map (second tab). To make things easier for them I also try to grab their geolocation and display it on the map. This works fine for laptops, but not for mobile devices. When I start the app on the laptop the browser asks me (popup) to share my location. On smartphones this doesn't happen. Any ideas why?

Here's my code:
The geolocation parts are in UI under "# get geolocation from user #" and in server under "# add device location #".

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyjs)
  library(leaflet)
  library(dplyr)
  library(sp)


  #####################################################################################################
  ## Server                                                                                       #####
  #####################################################################################################

  server <- function(input, output) {

    ## data frame (normally a bigger data frame) ## 
    df <- data.frame(lng = c(9.615772, 9.53677), lat = c(47.78331, 47.15224), label = c("Adress 1", "Adress 2"))


    ## render map ##
     output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
      # join input # 
      df_coord <- right_join(df, data.frame(label= input$address),
                              by="label"
                  )

      # add device location #
      if(!is.null(input$devicelat)){
        you <- data.frame(lng=input$devicelong, lat=input$devicelat, label="that's you")
        df_coord <- bind_rows(df_coord, you)
      }


      # convert to spacial points #
      data <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=df_coord[1:2], data = df_coord)

      # create map #
      mymap <- leaflet(data=data) %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addMarkers(lng= ~lng,
                   lat= ~lat,
                   popup= ~label
        )

      mymap
    })

  }



  #####################################################################################################
  ## User Interface                                                                               #####
  #####################################################################################################

  ui <- navbarPage(title = "amazing map",
                   ## TAB CHOOSE ADDRESS ##
                   tabPanel(title= "choose address",
                            # get geolocation from user #
                            tags$script('
                                        $(document).ready(function () {
                                          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

                                          function onError (err) {
                                          Shiny.onInputChange("geolocation", false);
                                          }

                                         function onSuccess (position) {
                                            setTimeout(function () {
                                                var coords = position.coords;
                                                console.log(coords.latitude + ", " + coords.longitude);
                                                Shiny.onInputChange("geolocation", true);
                                                Shiny.onInputChange("devicelat", coords.latitude);
                                                Shiny.onInputChange("devicelong", coords.longitude);
                                            }, 1100)
                                        }
                                        });
                                      '),
                            fluidRow(
                              column(6,
                                     offset = 3,
                                     wellPanel(
                                       checkboxGroupInput("address",
                                                          label = h3("Choose address to display"),
                                                          choiceNames = as.character(df$label),
                                                          choiceValues = df$label
                                       )
                                     )
                              )
                            )
                   ),
                   ## TAB MAP ##
                   tabPanel(title= "see the address",
                            tags$head(tags$style(HTML("#mymap {height: calc(100vh - 81px) !important;}")
                                      )),
                            fluidRow(leafletOutput("mymap", width =  "100%"))
                            )

  )


  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Are you using a `https://` URL to access your application from the smartphone?

Comment: No. Both times it's a `http://` URL. Doesn't seem to work at all with `https://`  
You can check the app on [this link](http://46.101.248.200:3838/marschplan/)

Comment: check the browser settings, might be declining by default

Comment: Geolocation is enabled in the browser settings. There is no problem with other peoples' apps that use geolocation. It also doesn't work on other peoples phones.